# building a dynamic query builder

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, multidimensional-array

created a suggestion based query builder
created 4 element in a 2d array called suggestion.

```
var field = []; //predefined values from the server key and value-based array getting only the key
var assignmentOp = [ "=", "!=", ">", "<",">=", "<=" ];
var values = [ "text", "date" ];
var logicalOp = [ "AND", "OR" ];
```

created these values to show as a suggestion `onfocus()` and call the `suggestion()` for displaying the value with a flag that increments (currentElementIndex) while selecting the suggestion with textarea in the page.

At the first loop the function works as expected.

**But at the second iteration**

The values iterate over the 4 elements in the suggestion and come back to the `currentElementIndex = 0` *ie.field*

*field value takes the entire string in the textarea for the finding the matching suggestion from the options. I want it to take only the previously input letter for searching the matching suggestion*

completed the `showSuggestion()`

```
function showSuggestion() {
        console.log("Inside showSuggestion:");
        console.log(currentElementIndex);

        if (event.which === 8) { // ASCII code , if the backspace key was pressed
            console.log("Clearing");
            if (currentElementIndex >= 0) {
                currentElementIndex--;
                console.log(
                        "after Decrementing the CurrentElementIndex Value:",
                        currentElementIndex);
            }
            if (textarea.includes(" ")) {
                var lastIndex = textarea.lastIndexOf(" ");
                textarea = textarea.substring(0, lastIndex);
                console.log("Textarea Text:", textarea);
            } else {
                //case where there's no space in the textarea, clear the whole textarea
                textarea = "";
                console.log("Textarea is empty.");
            }
        }
        //field
        var currentCategory = suggestion[currentElementIndex];
        console.log("currentCategory 1 :", currentCategory);
        if (currentCategory == field) {
            console.log("its field");
            var element = [];
            console.log("suggestion :", suggestion);
            console.log("Field:length :", suggestion[0].length);
            for (var i = 0; i < suggestion[0].length; i++) {
                element.push(suggestion[0][i].key);
            }
            console.log("element :", element);

            var allSuggestions = element;
            var matchingSuggestions = allSuggestions;

            // Get the value of the textarea when a letter is entered
            var searchText = event.target.value.slice(-1);
            console.log("searchText :", searchText);
            //Filter the matchingSuggestions
            if (searchText) {
                // If there is searchText, filter the suggestions
                matchingSuggestions = allSuggestions
                        .filter(function(suggestion) {
                            return suggestion.toLowerCase().includes(
                                    searchText.toLowerCase());
                        });
            }
            var cursorPosition = textarea[0].selectionEnd;
            console.log("cursorPosition :", cursorPosition);

            console.log("matchingSuggestions :", matchingSuggestions.key);
            // Clear the existing suggestion list
            suggestionList.empty();
            if (matchingSuggestions.length > 0) {
                matchingSuggestions.forEach(function(suggestions) {
                    //console.log("suggestions in the matching suggestion :",suggestions);
                    // Create a list item for each matching suggestion
                    var listItem = $("<li>").text(suggestions);
                    //console.log("listItem :", listItem.text());
                    // Add a click event listener to the list item to insert the suggestion when clicked
                    listItem.on("click",
                            function() {
                                replaceWithSuggestions(textarea, searchText,
                                        suggestion)
                                currentElementIndex++;
                            });
                    // Append the list item to the suggestion list
                    suggestionList.append(listItem);
                });
                // Display the suggestion list
                suggestionsDiv.css("display", "block");
            } else {
                // If there are no matching logicalOp, hide the suggestion list
                suggestionsDiv.css("display", "none");
            }
        }
        //assignmentOp
        console.log("currentCategory 2 :", currentCategory);
        if (currentCategory == assignmentOp) {
            console.log("its assignmentOp");
            var element = [];
            console.log("suggestion :", suggestion);
            console.log("Field:length :", suggestion[1].length);
            for (var i = 0; i < suggestion[1].length; i++) {
                element.push(suggestion[1][i]);
            }
            console.log("element :", element);
            // Clear the existing suggestion list
            suggestionList.empty();
            if (element.length > 0) {
                element.forEach(function(suggestions) {
                    console.log("suggestions in the matching suggestion :",
                            suggestions);
                    // Create a list item for each matching suggestion
                    var listItem = $("<li>").text(suggestions);
                    console.log("listItem :", listItem.text());
                    // Add a click event listener to the list item to insert the suggestion when clicked
                    listItem.on("click", function() {
                        insertSuggestion(suggestions);
                        currentElementIndex++;
                    });
                    // Append the list item to the suggestion list
                    suggestionList.append(listItem);
                });
                console.log("suggestionList:" + suggestionList);
                // Display the suggestion list
                suggestionsDiv.css("display", "block");
            } else {
                // If there are no matching logicalOp, hide the suggestion list
                suggestionsDiv.css("display", "none");
            }
        }
        //values
        console.log("currentCategory 3 :", currentCategory);
        if (currentCategory == values) {
            console.log("its values");
            var element = [];
            console.log("suggestion :", suggestion);
            console.log("Field:length :", suggestion[2].length);
            for (var i = 0; i < suggestion[2].length; i++) {
                element.push(suggestion[2][i]);
            }
            console.log("element :", element);
            // Clear the existing suggestion list
            suggestionList.empty();
            if (element.length > 0) {
                element.forEach(function(suggestions) {
                    console.log("suggestions in the matching suggestion :",
                            suggestions);
                    // Create a list item for each matching suggestion
                    var listItem = $("<li>").text(suggestions);
                    console.log("listItem :", listItem.text());
                    // Add a click event listener to the list item to insert the suggestion when clicked
                    listItem.on("click", function() {
                        insertSuggestion(suggestions);
                        currentElementIndex++;
                    });
                    // Append the list item to the suggestion list
                    suggestionList.append(listItem);
                });
                console.log("suggestionList:" + suggestionList);
                // Display the suggestion list
                suggestionsDiv.css("display", "block");
            } else {
                // If there are no matching logicalOp, hide the suggestion list
                suggestionsDiv.css("display", "none");
            }
        }

        //logicalOp
        console.log("currentCategory 4 :", currentCategory);
        if (currentCategory == logicalOp) {
            console.log("its logicalOp");
            var element = [];
            console.log("suggestion :", suggestion);
            console.log("Field:length :", suggestion[3].length);
            for (var i = 0; i < suggestion[3].length; i++) {
                element.push(suggestion[3][i]);
            }
            console.log("element :", element);
            //get the text in textarea
            var searchText = textarea.val();
            //Filter the matchingSuggestions
            // Clear the existing suggestion list
            suggestionList.empty();
            if (element.length > 0) {
                element.forEach(function(suggestions) {
                    console.log("suggestions in the matching suggestion :",
                            suggestions);
                    // Create a list item for each matching suggestion
                    var listItem = $("<li>").text(suggestions);
                    console.log("listItem :", listItem.text());
                    // Add a click event listener to the list item to insert the suggestion when clicked
                    listItem.on("click", function() {
                        insertSuggestion(suggestions);
                        currentElementIndex = 0;
                    });
                    // Append the list item to the suggestion list
                    suggestionList.append(listItem);
                });
                // Display the suggestion list
                suggestionsDiv.css("display", "block");
            } else {
                // If there are no matching logicalOp, hide the suggestion list
                suggestionsDiv.css("display", "none");
            }
        }
    }


//function to insertSuggestion
    function insertSuggestion(suggestion) {
        // Get the current text within the textarea
        var currentText = textarea.val();
        console.log("current text in the textarea:", currentText.substring(0,
                cursorPosition));
        // Get the current cursor position within the textarea
        var cursorPosition = textarea[0].selectionStart;
        console.log("cursorPosition :", cursorPosition);
        var newText = currentText.substring(0, cursorPosition) + suggestion
                + " ";
        console.log(textarea.val().substring(textarea[0].selectionEnd));
        console.log("newText :", newText);
        // Set the value of the textarea to the new text, effectively inserting the suggestion
        textarea.val(newText);
        // Hide the suggestion list
        suggestionsDiv.css("display", "none");
    }
```

Comment: The problem is your second loop. ```searchText``` is not being updated correctly.

Comment: If the user provides an input using the `searchText`, display relevant suggestions based on the input. If the user doesn't provide any input, show all available suggestions.
@KeyboardCorporation

Comment: Replace your ```showSuggestion``` function. Make sure that ```allSuggestions``` contains all suggestions for the current category. If ```searchText``` is not empty, ```matchingSuggestions``` will contain only the suggestions that start with ```searchText```. If ```searchText``` is empty, ```matchingSuggestions``` will contain all suggestions.